# SQL Insert multiple rows based on a date span

Tags: sql-server, date

I need to write sql for multiple inserts based on a date range.  For example I have member 12 that has a start date of 01/01/2014 through through 12/31/2014.  I need to insert a row each month (12 of them) into a table.  I need to compare this information to a table that has already been expanded in that way.  Any help would be appreciated.
Example Input

```
client    amount       start           end         numpymtmths

12      $3000      01/01/2014     03/31/2014     03

13      $700       06/01/2014     12/31/2014     07
```

need to expand it to look like:

```
client  amount     paydate     
12      $1000      201401    
12      $1000      201402  
12      $1000      201403    
13      $100       201406  
13      $100       201407    
13      $100       201408  
13      $100       201409  
13      $100       201410  
13      $100       201411  
13      $100       201412
```

Answer (score 0):

To split the data, you'll need either to have a table of numbers (or months) or create it dynamically for example with a CTE. The CTE solution could look something like this:

```
with n1(n) as (
  select 1 union all select 1 union all 
  select 1 union all select 1 union all 
  select 1 union all select 1 union all 
  select 1 union all select 1 union all 
  select 1 union all select 1
),
n(n) as (
  select row_number() over (order by (select null)) - 1 
  from n1 cross join n1 as n2
)

select client, amount / numpymtmths, dateadd(month, n.n, start) as month 
from payment
join n on n.n < numpymtmths
order by client, month
```

This is now limited for 100 months (10 x 10 numbers joined in the CTE).

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/dee75/2